# Customize the Windows 7 Games Explorer

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, gaming

I just upgraded my system to the Windows 7 RTM, and I've noticed they took away the ability to customize the shortcuts in the Games Explorer.

Is there a third-party application that would allow me to customize the shortcuts without having to do so manually? I know how to do it, but it's a pain, and I'd rather have a GUI do the dirty work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program available called [Vista Game Explorer Editor](http://gameeditor.webnode.com/).

[Reports](http://www.sevenforums.com/gaming/1775-game-explorer.html) are that it does work with Windows 7.

Comment: Well, it works, but it's really buggy and unintuitive. I'll wait for something else, and if nothing comes up, I'll mark this as the accepted answer. +1 for at least giving me something.

Comment: Actually, after reformatting my hard drive, this doesn't work at all. :(